# Filter Query Without Score in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to modify this query so that elastic search does *not* give it a score. I want my custom filter score to be the only thing giving any result a score. How do I accomplish this?

Each record should only every have a score of 0, 100, or 1000.

```
{
  "size":50, 
  "from":0, 
  "query" : {
    "custom_filters_score" : {
      "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
          "query" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                {"term":{"type":"alpha"}}, 
                {"field":{"sector":"exists"}}, 
                {"field":{"sector.sub":"exists"}}, 
                {"field":{"alpha_sector.sub.categories":"second"}}, 
                {"field":{"beta_sector.sub.columns":"first"}}, 
                {"term":{"beta_type":"beta"}}, 
                {"term":{"area":"624"}}
              ]
            }
          }, 
          "filter" : {
            "or" : [
              {
                "and" : [
                  {"term":{"area":"624"}}, 
                  {"term":{"start":"07242013"}}
                ]
              }, 
              {
                "and" : [
                  {"term":{"area":"624"}}, 
                  {"term":{"start":"blank"}}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }, 
      "filters" : [
        {"filter":{"term":{"resource":5726}}, "boost":"1000"}, 
        {"filter":{"term":{"alpha_resource":5726}}, "boost":"100"}
      ], 
      "score_mode":"sum"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here

```
            {"field":{"sector":"exists"}}, 
            {"field":{"sector.sub":"exists"}},
```

but in general, if you don't want part of your query to affect the score, just make it a filter. It's also will be better to use "bool" with "term" filters instead of "and"/"or"/"not"

```
{
  "size":50, 
  "from":0, 
  "query" : {
    "custom_filters_score" : {
      "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
          "query" : {
            "match_all": {}
          }, 
          "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                {"term":{"type":"alpha"}}, 
                {"query":{"field":{"sector":"exists"}}}, 
                {"query":{"field":{"sector.sub":"exists"}}}, 
                {"query":{"field":{"alpha_sector.sub.categories":"second"}}}, 
                {"query":{"field":{"beta_sector.sub.columns":"first"}}}, 
                {"term":{"beta_type":"beta"}}, 
                {"term":{"area":"624"}}
              ],
              "should" : [
                {
                  "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                      {"term":{"area":"624"}}, 
                      {"term":{"start":"07242013"}}
                    ]
                  }
                }, 
                {
                  "bool" : {
                    "must": [
                      {"term":{"area":"624"}}, 
                      {"term":{"start":"blank"}}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }, 
      "filters" : [
        {"filter":{"term":{"resource":5726}}, "boost":"1000"}, 
        {"filter":{"term":{"alpha_resource":5726}}, "boost":"100"}
      ], 
      "score_mode":"total"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I obfuscated the actual fields because they are sensitive so the data part of the query may not make a whole lot of sense, but the structure is accurate, I will give this a test when I crawl out from the other things I am working on and let you know if it worked!

Comment: Hi @imotov - Do you mind looking into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372951/elasticsearch-query-time-boosting-produces-result-in-inadequate-order?noredirect=1#comment62264775_37372951) of mine please?