# Elasticsearch query time boosting produces result in inadequate order

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

The ES search result for the given search keyword `one two three` seems to be wrong after applying `boost` feature per keyword. Please help me modifying my "faulty" query in order to accomplish "expected result" below as I described. I'm on ES **1.7.4** with LUCENE **4.10.4**

**Boosting criteria**  -`three` *is regarded as the most important keyword*:

```
word - boost
----   -----
one    1
two    2
three  3
```

**ES index content** - *just showing MySQL dump to make the post shorter*

```
mysql> SELECT id, title FROM post;
+----+-------------------+
| id | title             |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | one               |
|  2 | two               |
|  3 | three             |
|  4 | one two           |
|  5 | one three         |
|  6 | one two three     |
|  7 | two three         |
|  8 | none              |
|  9 | one abc           |
| 10 | two abc           |
| 11 | three abc         |
| 12 | one two abc       |
| 13 | one two three abc |
| 14 | two three abc     |
+----+-------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Expected ES query result** - *The user is searching for* `one two three`. *I'm not fussed about the order of equally scored records. I mean if record 6 and 13 switches places, I don't mind.*

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | title             | my scores for demonstration purposes
+----+-------------------+
|  6 | one two three     | (1+2+3 = 6)
| 13 | one two three abc | (1+2+3 = 6)
|  7 | two three         | (2+3 = 5)
| 14 | two three abc     | (2+3 = 5)
|  5 | one three         | (1+3 = 4)
|  4 | one two           | (1+2 = 3)
| 12 | one two abc       | (1+2 = 3)
|  3 | three             | (3 = 3)
| 11 | three abc         | (3 = 3)
|  2 | two               | (2 = 2)
| 10 | two abc           | (2 = 2)
|  1 | one               | (1 = 1)
|  9 | one abc           | (1 = 1)
|  8 | none              | <- This shouldn't appear
+----+-------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Unexpected ES query result** - *Unfortunately, This is what I get.*

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | title             | _score
+----+-------------------+
|  6 | one two three     | 1.0013864
| 13 | one two three abc | 1.0013864
|  4 | one two           | 0.57794875
|  3 | three             | 0.5310148
|  7 | two three         | 0.50929534
|  5 | one three         | 0.503356
| 14 | two three abc     | 0.4074363
| 11 | three abc         | 0.36586377
| 12 | one two abc       | 0.30806428
| 10 | two abc           | 0.23231897
|  2 | two               | 0.12812772
|  1 | one               | 0.084527075
|  9 | one abc           | 0.07408653
+----+-------------------+
```

**ES query**

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?post_dev" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "title": {
            "query": "one two three"
          }
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "one",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "two",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "three",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": "0",
  "size": "100"
}'
```

Some more test queries:

- This [query](http://pastebin.com/G5DLpfb7) doesn't produce any result.
- This [query](http://pastebin.com/HTCvLGvp) doesn't order correctly as seem [here](http://pastebin.com/BHcnZQti).

Comment: How did you decide the expected output? If "three" is the most important keyword how come "one two" coming before "three"? The thing you need to know is that boosting is not linear. If you boost a query with 2 does not with it will contribute to final score 2 times higher before. This is mostly due to normalization process. If you provide more meaningful feedback about how you end up with your expectations, I can try to help with the query again.

Comment: @Heval My expectation might be ambiguous based on my limited knowledge of boost or query itself so I tell you what exactly I need. Any `title` that contains most of the words is the better. e.g.: a record `one two three` (= `6` points) is better than `three` (= `3` points) or `two three` (5) is better than `one three` (4) or `one three` (5) is better than `three` (3). I hope you get the picture. I just used `"query": ["one","two","three"]` but it didn't work either. Anyway, I leave it to you for now. Thanks

Comment: I also updated "Expected ES query result" section above to provide better explanation.

Comment: Why is that `must` clause in there?

Comment: @femtoRgon I saw it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html). It is obvious that my query is not fit for the purpose in this particular case. If you have an answer&query that does what I want please share with me. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I believe the must clause doesn't really serve much purpose and just muddies the waters here.  I would remove the must block entirely.  I don't necessarily think that's going to solve the problem, though.  Doc 5 is probably above Doc 14 due to [length normalization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html).  Doc 4's score, however, I can't explain (nor reproduce).  You may need to examine the score there using the [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Index some test data
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/1" -d '{"title": "one"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/2" -d '{"title": "two"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/3" -d '{"title": "three"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/4" -d '{"title": "one two"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/5" -d '{"title": "one three"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/6" -d '{"title": "one two three"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/7" -d '{"title": "two three"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/8" -d '{"title": "none"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/9" -d '{"title": "one abc"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/10" -d '{"title": "two abc"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/11" -d '{"title": "three abc"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/12" -d '{"title": "one two abc"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/13" -d '{"title": "one two three abc"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test/doc/14" -d '{"title": "two three abc"}'
# Make test data available for search
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/test/_refresh?pretty"
# Search using function score
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/test/doc/_search?pretty" -d'{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "one two three"
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "title": "one"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "title": "two"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 2
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "title": "three"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 3
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost_mode": "replace"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "from": "0",
    "size": "100"
}'
```

Comment: If I could, I would give more that one +1. Thank you very much, it works perfectly fine. Good thing is, I haven't missed it by miles as I thought!